# Nginx PHP websocket issues

Tags: php, nginx, websocket

I've been trying to get websockets in nginx/php working for days now.

Ths is my current setup :

'Chat.php' path = root/src/MyApp/Chat.php

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // Store the new connection to send messages to later
         $this->clients->attach($conn);
         echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
        , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
             if ($from !== $client) {
            // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

'chat-server.php' path = root/bin/chat-server.php

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;
    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );
    $server->run();
```

Nginx conf

```
 location / {
            access_log off;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
            proxy_send_timeout 86400s;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

Using the Ratchet examples. I can get the normal CLI only messaging working just fine. If I try it in the browser, this error pops up in the console:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The server was indeed running at that point. Any ideas?

Comment: I think, Ratched can working without nginx, and I try to debug without nginx, try to check if ports are opened (telnet localhost 8080).

Is it worked without nginx (try to connect in js directly to 127.0.0.1 and 8080)?

Comment: You get error "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed" in browser, so it means that client connects directly to ratchet (port 8080). Is Is it so? Show your js code for connection

Answer (score 0):

you have to access your websocket from the browser using:

```
new WebSocket('ws://localhost/');
```

Nginx will then proxy this request (any request on `/`) to `http://localhost:8080;` where your PHP websocket implentation is listening on... hopefully